# ExecutorService to execute a single task n times by multiple threads (n thread "races")

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable

I need to execute a single task by multiple threads, such that when the first thread finishes and before any other thread finishes, all the threads are stopped and start the same task all over again. This should be performed n times.

My attempt is using `Callable<V>` and the method `invokeAny()` (that is why I use the set) but not sure how to accomplish the goal.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
Callable<String> task = () -> {
    someTask();
    return "";
};
Set<Callable<String>> tasks = new HashSet<>();
IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(i -> {
    tasks.add(task);
    executor.submit(task);
});
```

How to finish this? or any better solution?

Comment: `executor.submit(task);` will return a `Future<String>`.  You just need to wait for all of these to be completed.

Comment: Thanks but still not sure. they should start the task all over again when the first one has finished, so wondering how will I get notified when this happens? I thought of a loop that continuously checks if a thread finished but it seems a little wastefull to keep checking that. Not sure how to use the `Future<String>` result here.

Comment: *"when the first thread finishes and before any other thread finishes, all the threads are stopped and start the same task all over again"* Is it like a lengthy process, and each thread "makes an attempt" and when _one_ succeeds, the others are irrelevant and should stop?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the case

Comment: Are you thinking that if you run multiple in parallel and select the fastest one, you'll save time over running it a single time?  What's the use case here?

Comment: Yes, this is merely for a simulation, and definitely not for an efficiency boost. It may have value if we want to simulate the behaviour of multiple users with different computational power using some service

Comment: Yep, that seems fair :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one suggestion:

```
class Task implements Callable<Integer> {

    private final static Random RND = new Random();

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        try {
            // Work on task for a random duration
            Thread.sleep(RND.nextInt(5000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("I was interrupted."
                    + "Someone else probably solved the task before me.");
            return -1;
        }

        // Return some dummy value
        return RND.nextInt();
    }
}

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final int numWorkers = 3; // number of tasks to run in parallel

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numWorkers);

        // Solve task 5 times. (Change it to while (true) { ...} if you like.)
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            CompletionService<Integer> completionService =
                    new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);

            Future<?>[] futures = new Future<?>[numWorkers];
            for (int j = 0; j < numWorkers; j++) {
                futures[j] = completionService.submit(new Task());
            }

            Future<Integer> firstToComplete = completionService.take();

            try {
                Integer result = firstToComplete.get();
                System.err.println("We got a result: " + result);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // Should not happen. Future has completed.
            }

            // Cancel all futures (it doesn't matter that we're cancelling
            // the one that has already completed).
            for (int j = 0; j < numWorkers; j++) {
                futures[j].cancel(true);
            }
        }

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

If the task you're solving does not respond to interrupts, passing `true` to `cancel(...)` won't help. In that case I'd suggest you do the following changes:

1. Create an `AtomicBoolean done` variable in the outer `for` loop.
2. Pass this to the constructor to `Task` and save it in a field in `Task`.
3. In the task solving process, check `done` flag ever so often, and cancel the attempt if `done` is `true`.
4. Instead of calling `cancel` on the tasks after the first result is in, set `done` to `true` and wait for the other threads to return.